# Why Ngrok access encounter error 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: nat, ngrok

I established a Ngrok tunnel on localhost, started service on port 8080, also run the command `./ngrok http 8080`. All is ready, but cannot succeed:

[image]

access localhost:4040, see this following:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ngrok errors '502 bad gateway'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598428/ngrok-errors-502-bad-gateway)

Answer (score 2):

I use below command, it works well

`ngrok http 127.0.0.1:8080 -host-header="127.0.0.1:8080"`